# PC motherboard failed?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer

My [Asus M4A77T](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A77T/) motherboard appears (to me) to have died. These are the exact symptoms I observe:

- the PC doesn't boot: when I press `power`, the CPU fan starts up, but then falls into a weird pattern of rotation speed oscillation
- no combination of plugged-in RAM units helps, and neither does disconnecting all peripherals and disks
- it's not the graphics card (I have a spare and there's no change when I use it)
- when pressing and holding `power`, the machine eventually shuts off (as expected), but when *depressing* the button, it starts up again, which I find surprising
- a red LED (apparently the "DRAM LED") is on without interruption until I shut the machine down ([motherboard photo](https://snag.gy/UCDFtY.jpg) and [LED close-up](https://snag.gy/xuPGrQ.jpg))

This looks to me like there might be something wrong with the RAM sockets or maybe damaged/worn out RAM leads within the board itself.

Could it be the CPU? The battery? Something else? Any simple way to check before I go out and buy a replacement board?

Comment: It can be all the above. The fact it's not even attempting to POST indicates it's not a memory problem more than likely

Comment: You can verify it's not a DDR3 problem by removing all the memory moduals and attempting to start the machine (but again) what you describe isn't a memory problem

Comment: I just had something similar happen to my ASUS MB after updating the BIOS. It turned out the DRAM timing got changed to a speed the DRAM didn't support. I changed the speed back to the DRAM default (2666), and suddenly everything was fine. Took me two hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific answer, but I can provide an answer in the form of a diagnostic checklist you should perform on the system to determine the root cause of the behavior:

1. Remove CMOS battery for 1 minute while system is completely unplugged from the wall, then replace it with a known-good CMOS battery. If this resolves your issue, the problem was with your CMOS battery.
2. Replace PSU with known-good PSU. If this resolves the problem it is your PSU at fault.
3. RTFM, or be subjected to the horrible font rendering I am currently enduring in order to play Battlefield 1 with as little vRAM overhead as possible:
   [image]
   If this is the light that is on, your RAM is likely at fault in some way and should be replaced with a known-good single stick in each of the four DIMM slots until something works. Also do check out the other good advice ASUS provides in that section.
4. Make sure you have a speaker connected to the board. If this speaker provides you with beep codes, look them up. They may provide an answer as to *how* exactly your RAM got all fubar, as well as how you might go about unfubaring them.
5. Replace CPU with known-good CPU. If this resolves the problem, the CPU was at fault.
6. If none of the above works, problem is with the motherboard.

Anecdote: I have had the same CPU fan behavior occur several times on machines I was working with. The problem in the last one was RAM related - and resolved simply by reseating the RAM and powering cycling the computer - but I can't remember my resolution in the instances before that. I don't suspect it will be that easy for you given it already sounds like you've moved the RAM around quite a bit. If you have any information to provide as to *when* this problem began, that might help us determine the cause and therefore the likely resolution.

Comment: Bought a new battery, measured voltages to be 3.18V for the old and 3.2V for the new, put in the new battery anyway and voila: the machine awoke! ;) I have a sneaking suspicion that it would have worked with the old battery as well once the BIOS was restarted, but I couldn't be bothered to check. ;) Thanks for the help, Adam, Rahmound and Bill!